# JShell: Accessing Objects Created by Snippets

Tags: jshell

I am very confused about something and I would appreciate some insight here.

Say I want to build a GUI that visualizes what is going on inside JShell, i.e. how the, by snippets created objects reference each other and what, by Snippets created objects are contained inside my running instance of JShell. How do I access these objects, and most of all, how do I access how they reference each other?

A concrete example: I create a JShell instance, pass it a few snippets created by the user, which cause the creation of, for example, an ArrayList, a few objects, and add said objects to said ArrayList.

How do I access this ArrayList and the objects contained within it to visualize this in a GUI?

To clarify further:

```
//say I create a Jshell:  
JShell jShell = JShell.create();  
//Which then evauletes user code passed from the GUI:  
jShell.eval(userCode)  

//userCode could be following lines each passed as separate Strings:  
“ArrayList<TestObject> allObj = new ArrayList<TestObject>();”  
“TestObject tst = new TestObject();”  
“TestObject tst2 = new TestObject();”  
“allObj.add(tst);”  
“allObj.add(tst2);”
```

How do I access “allObj”?

How do I access “tst” and the object it points to? (the “TestObject”instance that “tst” points to);

I know eval() returns a list of SnippetEvents which contain the changed/added snippets, however, I can’t get my head around how to access the objects created by those snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your classpath has access to the TestObj you could implement Serializable on that object. Upon completion of the eval run another method automatically that serializes the output. Then you can deserialize that object inside your code.